# How can I flatten a torus only on certain axes so that it looks more like a flattened band?

Tags: modeling

I would like to flatten a torus so that it looks more like this:

[image]

I have already tried playing with the basic torus parameters but without success.

How can I do this?

Comment: A "band"... You mean a flat ring? And what is the final goal? If you don't need to animate the flattening, you'd better to start with a circle, and extrude it with scaling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you want a band with some thickness, like this:

[image: Target]

There are obviously many ways to make such a shape. Here are a couple:

## Scaling a torus:

1. Add torus
2. Scale on the Z (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>)
3. Optionally enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and scale along the normals with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>

[image: Torus solution]

## Circle with subsurf modifier:

1. Add a circle (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Mesh > Circle*)
2. Extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) into a band shape
3. Add subsurf modifier (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>1-5, where the number refers to the number of viewport subdivisions)
4. Optionally add loopcuts to flatten some sides of the band

[image: Circle solution]

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for! thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Other interactive way to do this is using a curve as a Bevel Object on a circle.

Create a Circle by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and choose curve->circle

[image]
[image]

Enter edit mode and create the profile you want by deforming the circle on the x axis.

[image]
[image]

Exit edit mode and create a new circle.

[image]

In the properties tab for the curve assign the 1st circle as Bevel Object.

[image]

If the shape is not what you want, you can readjust the first curve in edit mode.
[image]
[image]
[image]