# Is it possible to get back to `Add mode`?

Tags: modeling

After for example a Torus has been added, you can specify major segments, minor segments, radii, etc.

After some clicking around i cant seem to get back to these settings anymore.
is it possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options at the bottom of the Tool Shelf (left Panel in the 3D view) and the 'F6 menu' only exist when you're adding an object.

If you add an object (Cube, UV Sphere, Torus...) and press enter to accept the addition, you're too late in changing the options with the F6 menu.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > Add Torus, press <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>T</kbd>, now you can change the settings, before you press enter or carry out a further action.

Objects you add are not procedural, you cannot just change their parameters at any time,but only when you add them to your scene.

Answer (score 0):

For an interactive way to make a Torus, use curve as Bevel object on a circle. That way you can always go back and re-edit the shape.

Details here:
[How can I flatten a torus only on certain axes so that it looks more like a flattened band?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9056/how-can-i-flatten-a-torus-only-on-certain-axes-so-that-it-looks-more-like-a-flat)