# How to make redo last pop-up to not disappear after cursor moved out?

Tags: modeling, interface

I would like to have this window permanently on screen

[image]

Comment: You can only have it onscreen permanently by having the toolbar open, see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9100/is-it-possible-to-get-back-to-add-mode/9101#9101

Comment: I need separate window for this, T panel  becomes too messy, i dont want expand top or bottom part of panel every time i need some tool.