# Bumps on my mesh (and no edges there)

Tags: modeling, edges

Hi everyone i donot know what has happened to  my mesh it display many bumps in render mode but when i look in solid view mode there a are no bumps and there is not even an edge there.
[image: Look Closely there.]

[image: Now look here, Different.]

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/how-to-flatten-a-face-to-avoid-distortion-make-an-ngon-planar and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16258/why-is-this-surface-wrinkly

Comment: you have nonplaner faces, meaning they are not flat. Because a face can only be flat you are seeing the tessellation.

Comment: you can use the bundled 3d print addon to check mesh problems like those (and mode)

Comment: thank you very muck mr zak it worked i am gretly thankful