# Turning a 2D profile into a 3D ring

Tags: modeling

I have tried modelling this myself several different ways, and attempted a number of tutorials but just seem to be having no luck.

I have the following 2D profile that I created:

[image]

It's intended to match the profile of my wife's wedding band so that I can 3D print a dress ring to match. The flat base is 17.5mm from the center of the modelling area. I have then used spin to turn the profile into a ring.

[image]

Now when I attempt to see if the model is any good for printing, i.materialise complains about it without being specific as to what the problem is. I used a "Non-manifold" method to try work out what's wrong but I have no idea what to actually do to fix whatever is wrong. I have removed duplicates and I can't see any odd joints or something that would be causing issues....not that I'd know even if they were poking me in the face.

I have tried other methods to create the ring but this seems to be the only way that will allow me to get the exact profile I require.

Any thoughts, ideas, or alternate ways to achieve the same goal?

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: probably inverted normals (outer faces are inside). In edit mode, select all and ctrl+n.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9056/how-can-i-flatten-a-torus-only-on-certain-axes-so-that-it-looks-more-like-a-flat/9097#9097

Comment: As lemon mentioned the most common problem is inverted normals. If you made it from a mesh it might also be that when the loop closes the vertices aren't merged and there's an invisible gap. Try removing doubles and re calculating normals afterwards.

Comment: It was the normals, thanks people :) Now to find out what normals are lol

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21190/what-are-face-normals

Answer (score 1):

Use your 2d object as bevel object of a bezier circle object.

If 2d object is a mesh, convert it to curve, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *> Curve from mesh*.